# how to encode video in php and save that encoded video in a file and then decode and save it in a database

Tags: php, android, html

I had encode a video in Php using html and now i want to decode and save it in php .
But I do not know how to save encoded video and how to get it for decoding.
Do help me , I am attaching my code here

```
<html>
  <video controls>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo getEncodedVideoString('mp4','add.mp4');?>">
  </video>
</html> 
<?php
  include("connect.php");
  function getEncodedVideoString($type, $file) {
    $filename= 'data:video/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
    echo $filename;
?>
```

Comment: <html>
<video controls> 

   <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo getEncodedVideoString('mp4','add.mp4');?>"> 
</video>
</html>
<?php
include("connect.php");
function getEncodedVideoString($type, $file) { 
   $filename= 'data:video/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)); 
 echo $filename;
?>

Comment: I added your code in your question to be more readable

Comment: @ Diego C Nascimento: No I just want to again decode it in .mp4 format and that should be store somewhere in existing database

Comment: ohk then please give me the way to store that encoded video in a file.

Comment: @Diego C Nascimento Sorry to confuse you but actually my scenario is I will get encoded video from android app then I have to decode that video and have to store on myserver. And for dummy purpose I am trying  to encode it and then want to decode and get stored that video on my database . Hope you understand my scenario and give me positive result..

Comment: @Diego C Nascimento I am not able to communicate with my client thats'y wanted to do this task in a dummy and encoded a video but now dont know how to proceed.. Please fix my issue :P

Comment: I already tried this method but when I am passing $filename in parameter of base64_decode() it is giving an error of undefined variable filename

Comment: $fp=fopen("/address".$filename,'w')
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($getChunks)){
 $chuncks=$row['chunkpart'];
 $var=base64_decode($chunks);
  fwrite($fp,$var)

Comment: well according to the error you say `$filename` is not defined.

Comment: $var=base64_decode($filename);
$fp = fopen('2013-02-21_14-52-35_968.mp4', 'w');
fwrite($fp,$var);
fclose($fp);

Comment: Till now my work is pending...

Comment: Did your problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Just saw your question... :) You are missing a curly bracket `}`

```
echo $filename; <---- Why echo $filename???
```

Use this Instead:

```
function getEncodedVideoString($type, $file) {
    return 'data:video/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
}`
```